# SQL adding leading zero

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a database using Oracle. This is a query, that I need to turn into function:

```
SELECT master_id,
    EXTRACT(month FROM TRUNC(job_start, 'MM')) month_num,
    (SUM(CAST(job_stop AS DATE) - CAST(job_start AS DATE)) * 60 * 24) / ((LAST_DAY(TRUNC(job_start, 'MM')) - TRUNC(job_start, 'MM')) + 1) / 60 hours
    FROM T_SCHEDULE
    GROUP BY TRUNC(job_start, 'MM'), master_id
    ORDER BY master_id ASC, month_num;
```

T_SCHEDULE table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE T_SCHEDULE
(
    sched_id number(4) NOT NULL,
    master_id number(10) REFERENCES T_MASTER(master_id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
    client_id number(10) REFERENCES T_CLIENT(client_id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
    box_num number(5) REFERENCES T_BOX(box_num) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
    car_num varchar2(10) REFERENCES T_CAR(car_num) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
    price number(7) NOT NULL,
    job_start timestamp NOT NULL,
    job_stop timestamp NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(sched_id)
);
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4001, 1001, 2002, 3002, 'Р232ХВ', 20000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 12:30:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 17:30:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4002, 1002, 2003, 3003, 'А847КР', 8000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 08:15:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 12:15:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4003, 1003, 2004, 3005, 'С966ЕС', 5000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 10:45:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 13:45:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4004, 1004, 2005, 3001, 'Т138УВ', 10000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 10:30:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 15:30:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4005, 1005, 2006, 3006, 'Р364ВЕ', 15000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 09:00:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 11:00:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4006, 1001, 2007, 3005, 'О117УУ', 7000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-03 14:10:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-03 17:10:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4007, 1002, 2008, 3002, 'Н439АМ', 30000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-03 10:40:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-03 15:40:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4008, 1003, 2009, 3003, 'О896МТ', 4000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 14:30:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 18:30:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4009, 1004, 2010, 3004, 'Т694КС', 12000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-03 09:50:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-03 17:50:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4010, 1005, 2001, 3001, 'У601КК', 9000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 16:00:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 20:00:00.0');
```

Although, I don't think it's relevant to the question. When I run the query, the output looks like this:[image]

Which is perfect, however I need to turn this query into a procedure, so this is what I got:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE avg_load
IS
    rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN rc FOR SELECT master_id,
        EXTRACT(month FROM TRUNC(job_start, 'MM')) month_num,
        (SUM(CAST(job_stop AS DATE) - CAST(job_start AS DATE)) * 60 * 24) / ((LAST_DAY(TRUNC(job_start, 'MM')) - TRUNC(job_start, 'MM')) + 1) / 60 hours
        FROM T_SCHEDULE
        GROUP BY TRUNC(job_start, 'MM'), master_id
        ORDER BY master_id ASC, month_num;
    dbms_sql.return_result(rc);
END;
```

When I call this procedure I get this output:

[image]

As you can see, there are no leading zeros. I tried various stuff like using `to_char`:

```
rtrim(to_char(num, 'FM90.99'), '.')
```

And while it does add a leading zero, this is what the output looks like:
[image]

Looks like, it makes the string extremely long, but I have no clue why.
So how can I add leading zeros without overextending the table? Something like the first screenshot.

P.S. I am using Oracle SQL Developer 21.2.1.204.

Comment: Your questions sound like display issues. That is not a feature of SQL, but of your user interface. What are you using - SQL\*Plus? Tell us what you are using, so we can tell you how you can get the result you need; it's about user interface settings, which you can control, not about your SQL statement or your data.

Comment: @mathguy I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are trying to do this in SQL Developer, in Script mode (running a PL/SQL program).

Before running the program run the following SQL*Plus command, supported also by SQL Developer:

```
column hours format 0.99   --  or 0.99999999 - however many decimals you need
```

Note that this is not a SQL or PL/SQL statement; it does not need to be terminated with semicolon (although SQL Developer is tolerant - it will understand the command and execute it correctly even if you do use a semicolon at the end).

Comment: I am running the procedure like this: `begin avg_load; end;` Should it be like this: `column hours format 0.99 begin avg_load; end;`? (Sorry for the way the code looks in the comments).